# How to fix "CS0117" error in unity with vuforia framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, vuforia

i develop augmanted reality project on unity with vuforia framework. I have to use many scene so i need to change screen button. when i write screen change script on button, i encounter this error:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHz8Y.png

also my script

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuRB6.png

how can i fix this problem ?

Comment: [Application.LoadLevel](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html) has an upcase L at the start of Level, while you've written `Application.Loadlevel`. Please paste your code to the question directly instead of using an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application.LoadLevel.html):

> ### Application.LoadLevel
>
> Obsolete public static void LoadLevel(int index);
>
> Description
> Note: This is now obsolete. Use `SceneManager.LoadScene` instead.